# angular-cli what is the difference between version of package.json and ng -v

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have in my package.json this versions of dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",


"devDependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
```

and in the project when execute ng -v

```
$ ng -v
@angular/animations: 4.2.4
@angular/common: 4.2.4
@angular/compiler: 4.2.4
@angular/core: 4.2.4
@angular/forms: 4.2.4
@angular/http: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.2.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.2.4
@angular/router: 4.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.0.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.2.4
```

what is the current version of @angular in the project 4.0.0 or 4.2.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The versions in `package.json` are version ranges.

For example, if the version of `@angular/core` there is `^4.0.0`, this is like `4.x.x`, so depending on the last time you ran `npm install` (with no arguments), the actual version of `@angular/core` you might have in `node_modules` might be `4.0.1` or `4.2.5` etc.

Another example is `typescript`. It might show in `package.json` as `~2.3.0`, which is like `2.3.x`, you actual version might be `2.3.4`.

You can check the version truly installed of a package by running `npm ls`, for example `npm ls typescript` will show all versions of `typescript` package either called directly from `package.json`, or coming as a dependency of another package.

The `Angular/cli` version is very specific in your provided `package.json`, and set to `1.0.6`.

You would also have a global install (not specific to the project that has the `package.json` file) of `@angular/cli`. You can check its version by running `npm ls -g @angular/cli`.

This is very close to `ng -v`. What `ng -v` tells you is:

- What's the globally installed version of `@angular/cli`
- What's the locally installed version of `@angular/cli` (the one in `node_modules`, not the range specific in `package.json`).
  This is important in case you have both, as having different versions of both might causes issues.
- What are the locally installed versions (not the ranges) of other Angular packages that you need to ensure are in sync

Answer (score 1):

Your previous `package.json` did not have `@angular/cli`, If you talk about other packages in general, this will be the explanation:   It is `4.2.4`, the `^` says, take a package `4.0.0` or greater than that, while doing a fresh `npm install` you would have got the latest version. To stick to the same version on all development machines (if working in a team), I would recommend giving exact dependencies in `package.json` coz new versions might break the code in a fresh install.